# Celestia Gnome program stuck on load!

Tags: debian

I have Debian 8 Jessie and installed the package Celestia Gnome. It was working fine until recently, when I run the program again it stuck at the very beginning.
It should start loading with image of the earth, but it loads an image of the sun and stuck. If someone had the same problem with this package pleas help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. First of all the problem started after installing NVidia drivers package on Debian 8. Some OpenGL options was enabled, one of which did the problem I mention.
To fix the problem you have to enter NVidia X Server Settings application an on the OpenGL Settings to disable the 'Sync to VBlank' check box, see the picture bellow.

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

Now I have to open NVIDIA X Server Settings each time after login in order to apply those settings. So the only problem left is to make those settings load at startup.